# How to use command line parameters with phing

Tags: command-line, target, phing

Is it possible with phing to implements some Task depending on command line?

Ex:

phing install tag=1.0 dest=/tmp/1.0

I actually only see 3 ways to do it

- phing install -Dtag=1.0 -Ddest=/tmp/1.0
- using a prompt (there is something like a PromptTask)
- implementing my task and playing with $argv (global)

When calling a phing target from command line, are the other command line arguments useless ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that property definition with -D is the official way: http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/175

Comment: It is described in official CLI docs

http://www.phing.info/docs/stable/webhelp/sec.commandlineargs.html

Comment: Hi there, above link seems broken today, tks.

Comment: Up to date link: https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/sec.commandlineargs.html

Comment: Even more up-to-date: https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/chunkhtml/sec.commandlineargs.html